# Phpunit testsuite name

Tags: phpunit

I use phpunit and webdriver.
In my test.php file, I try to get the name of the testsuite from the phpunit.xml file.

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="myTestsuite">
        <directory>./tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Do you know, how can I access the testsuite name?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible at the moment.

I created an issue in PHPUnit repository to discuss. https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/4468

Comment: I need it as well. I need to be able to disable some testsuites for some developers to avoid giving them secret api keys

Answer (score -3):

You can use `simplexml_load_file` to load the file and access the attribute using the following code:

```
$xml =  simplexml_load_file('phpunit.xml');
echo $xml->testsuites->testsuite->attributes()->name;
```

Comment: This would not work with morethan one testsuite - you wouldn't know which is the one you're in.